# Sending pure byte[] over wcf without any overhead

Tags: c#, wcf, arrays

I am going to send and receive data over ***wcf***. The application that I am working on is server, I recieve byte[] and I have to send byte[] to the client also.
I don't know which applicaion or programming language they(client) are using, I just know they are excepting to recieve a ***byte[] without any overhead or metadata***.

Is this doable with wcf? Can I somehow configure the wcf to send just byte[] without inline metadata being added to the byte[]?

I know there is another option to diretly listen to the socket and send/recieve byte[] direct from the socket but I thought wcf might be a better option.

I really appreciate any help!

Comment: I don't know a lot about wcf so that's why this is a comment, but if you want to have as little overhead as possible you can read about UDP over wcf here:https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms751494(v=vs.110).aspx NOTE that UDP has no parity check so your data can get corrupt on it's way, but will be more than cool for audio/video streams

Comment: This is actually the question, how the client is going to sent data? Will it simply open socket connection, start listener and write bytes awaiting response or will that be bytes send as http message?

Answer (score 1):

If you can implement that with WCF of course, but you will have to develop lots of stuff for that. But it can be worth (IMHO), only if you are going to decode this incoming **byte[]** into objects on your side anyway, process deserialized data and then serialize response and send it back.
To do that you will have to implement your own **MessageEncoder**, **MessageEncoderFactory** and plug it into WCF pipeline for some binding. [See here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms751486.aspx)  one example an example.

[Here is one more great sample](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosfigueira/archive/2011/11/09/wcf-extensibility-message-encoders.aspx). Actually it is worth to look on [whole set of the articles about WCF extesibility](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosfigueira/archive/2011/03/14/wcf-extensibility.aspx).

**If you need simply get bytes, process binary data and send a binary result, I would implement simple service which listen TCP port. It will be much faster to develop, and will work also much faster and fully under your control.**